# Как перенаправлять tcp-трафик только для определенного процесса?

Tags: c++, windows, minecraft

Появилась необходимость перенаправлять весь tcp-трафик через свой сервер на примере игры Minecraft, но только для процесса этой игры. Пробовал создавать правило для процесса через утилиты вроде Proxifier или ProxyCap, но это не сработало. Пробовал также ставить хуки в ws2_32.dll на функции getaddrinfo и connect. Но это также не дало результатов, ибо при срабатывании хука getaddrinfo прогружается список серверов, в котором все сервера заменены на мой, но подключиться к нему нельзя. А при срабатывании хука connect вылетает Network is unreachable. Сам код хуков:

```
int __stdcall hooks::detour::hk_connect( SOCKET s, const sockaddr *name, int namelen ) {
    sockaddr_in sockaddrIn = { };
    memcpy( &sockaddrIn, name, sizeof sockaddrIn );
    sockaddrIn.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "127.0.0.1" );
    sockaddrIn.sin_port = htons( 25565 );
    return hooks::original::o_connect( s, reinterpret_cast< const sockaddr * >( &sockaddrIn ), namelen );
}

int __stdcall hooks::detour::hk_getaddrinfo( PCSTR pNodeName, PCSTR pServiceName, const ADDRINFOA *pHints, PADDRINFOA *ppResult ) {
    return hooks::original::o_getaddrinfo( "localhost", pServiceName, pHints, ppResult );
}
```

Посоветуйте рабочие утилиты для перенаравления всего tcp-трафика только для определенного процесса или помогите с хуками.

Comment: https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip почти стандарт судя по англоязычным SO

Comment: нет, это не сработало